# Combining two arrays into one with combined elements

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

C# .net windows form framework.
I was trying to combine two 1-D arrays into one 1-D arrays, that combines element from first and second into one new element pair in third array (like "a" and "b" into "a + b"), that have the length of one with lower element count. I getting error about exceptions but from my understanding it should work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] chlopcy = new string[] { "Tomek", "Michał", "Grzegorz", "Damian", "Daniel", "Kamil", "Paweł", "Krzysiu", "Wojtek", "Kuba" };
    string[] dziewczyny = new string[] { "Iwona", "Marta", "Ania", "Martyna", "Agnieszka", "Zofia", "Angelika", "Asia", "Joanna", "Ola" };
    string[] pary;

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox3.Items.Clear();
    for (int y = 0; y <= (listBox1.Items.Count - 1); y++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z <= (listBox2.Items.Count - 1); z++)
        {
            if (z == y)
            {
                string[] pary = new string[z] ;
                pary[z] = listBox1.Items[y] + " i " + listBox2.Items[z];
                listBox3.Items.Add(pary[z]);
            }
            if (z > y)
            {
                string[] pary = new string[y];
                pary[y] = listBox1.Items[y] + " i " + listBox2.Items[y];
                listBox3.Items.Add(pary[z]);
            }
            if (z < y)
            {
                string[] pary = new string[z];
                pary[y] = listBox1.Items[z] + " i " + listBox2.Items[z];
                listBox3.Items.Add(pary[z]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output, and what exception did you get?

Comment: You should single-step through the code in a debugger. However, on the first pass through the loops, `x` and `y` will both be zero, and the case `if (z == y)` will be true. So then the code creates a `pary` array of size zero (because `z` is zero) and then tries to access element `0` which, of course, does not exist because the array has size zero.

Comment: I im have two arrays of names and try to create a pair out of them. I can add more names to both arrays. Result is array that combines elements of same position into one element ("a + b"), if one array have more elements, it create only element of lower amount.

Comment: Also i can add more names to arrays in program arleady.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] chlopcy = new string[] { "Tomek", "Michał", "Grzegorz", "Damian", "Daniel", "Kamil", "Paweł", "Krzysiu", "Wojtek", "Kuba" };
    string[] dziewczyny = new string[] { "Iwona", "Marta", "Ania", "Martyna", "Agnieszka", "Zofia", "Angelika", "Asia", "Joanna", "Ola" };
    string[] pary;

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pary = chlopcy.Zip(dziewczyny, (a, b) => $"{a} i {b}").ToArray();

        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.AddRange(pary);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but when i try to add more elements in program it doesnt show new ones.

Comment: It's because the 'chlopcy' and 'dziewczyny' array's are not updating. When you add something to the listBox1 and listBox2, you should update the 'chlopcy' and 'dziewczyny' arrays.

You could also change the .Zip variables, like this:
[link](https://freeimage.host/i/b1HhKX)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** Go to bottom for your solution. However I recommend to read my explaination below to enhance your development skills.

Lets break down your code so that you understand what is actually going on.

***1. the `for` loop inside another `for` loop.***
To translate that to "human language" it means.

1. Take **item 1** of **array 1**
2. Then loop over **all items** from **array 2** while still being in the **FIRST cycle** of **array 1**
3. Then take **item 2** from **array 1**
4. Then loop over **all items** from **array 2 AGAIN** while being in the **SECOND cycle** of **array 1**

Your code (if you correct all other issues) will result in: (array1 * array2 = 100 items)

```
"Tomek i Iwona", "Tomek i Marta", "Tomek i Ania", .... , "Tomek i Ola",
"Michał i Iwona", "Michał i Marta", "Michał i Ania", .... , "Michał i Ola",
...
"Kuba i Iwona", "Kuba i Marta", "Kuba i Ania", .... , "Kuba i Ola",
```

Your request in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261014/combining-two-arrays-into-one-with-combined-elements#comment131108257_74261014) explains that you want to go side by side. And take item `N` from array 1 together with item `N` from array 2 (where `N` is the index in your iteration)

This means you want **ONE loop** without an inner loop.

***2. your first if-statement will compare first time if 0 == 0***
The first time you enter array 1 and immedately enter array 2, your `x` and `y` variables are `0`. So that means you create `pary` as `new string[0]`. After that you try to assign a value to this array which does simply allow zero items.

Think of what happens the second-tenth time that `x` and `y` are equal.

```cs
// example y and z = 10
string[] pary = new string[10]; // do you need an array???
pary[10] = listBox1.Items[10] + " i " + listBox2.Items[10];  
// Ah!!! no you don't. Since you only use index=10. So you skip index 0-9 = 10 items in the array
listBox3.Items.Add(pary[10]);

// Would this work? ;)
string value = listBox1.Items[10] + " i " + listBox2.Items[10];
listBox3.Items.Add(value);
```

***3. `y <= (listBox1.Items.Count - 1)`***
Yes it works but you can also do `y < listBox1.Items.Count`. Makes your code slightly more readable.

**Possible solutions**
Remark. I did not include listBox 1, 2 and 3 since I assumed that chlopcy, dziewczyny and pary are the listboxes you are refering to.

---

Short approach

```cs
string[] chlopcy = new string[] { "Tomek", "Michał", "Grzegorz", "Damian", "Daniel", "Kamil", "Paweł", "Krzysiu", "Wojtek", "Kuba"};
string[] dziewczyny = new string[] { "Iwona", "Marta", "Ania", "Martyna", "Agnieszka", "Zofia", "Angelika", "Asia", "Joanna", "Ola", "One item more" };

string[] largestArray = chlopcy.Length > dziewczyny.Length ? chlopcy : dziewczyny; // Save largest array
int zipAmount = chlopcy.Length < dziewczyny.Length ? chlopcy.Length : dziewczyny.Length; // save shortest amount

string[] pary = new string[largestArray.Length];

pary = chlopcy.Zip(dziewczyny, (a, b) => $"{a} i {b}").Union(largestArray.Skip(zipAmount).Take(largestArray.Length - zipAmount)).ToArray();
```

---

More readable approach

```cs
string[] chlopcy = new string[] { "Tomek", "Michał", "Grzegorz", "Damian", "Daniel", "Kamil", "Paweł", "Krzysiu", "Wojtek", "Kuba"};
string[] dziewczyny = new string[] { "Iwona", "Marta", "Ania", "Martyna", "Agnieszka", "Zofia", "Angelika", "Asia", "Joanna", "Ola", "One item more" };

int largestAmout = chlopcy.Length > dziewczyny.Length ? chlopcy.Length : dziewczyny.Length; // Save largest array

string[] pary = new string[largestAmout];

for(int index = 0; index < largestAmout; index++)
{
    if(index < chlopcy.Length && index < dziewczyny.Length)
    {
        // Both arrays has elements at index
        pary[index] = $"{chlopcy[index]} i {dziewczyny[index]}";
    }
    else if(index >= chlopcy.Length)
    {
        // chlopcy has less items than dziewczyny so dziewczyny should add the remaining items
        pary[index] = $"<nothing> i {dziewczyny[index]}";
    }
    else
    {
        // dziewczyny has less items than chlopcy so chlopcy should add the remaining items
        pary[index] = $"{chlopcy[index]} i <nothing>";
    }
}
```